# Using Google Maps API with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to design an app for use on both iOS & Android. It will have a few tabs, with one tab dedicated to navigation. I'm hoping to use the Google Maps API to run the map, which will include basic mapping features such as route planning.

I've done some research into PhoneGap and from what I can gather I can use web technologies (HTML, Javascript etc.), in which I already have a proficiency, to build the app, which I can then package into an iOS and/or Android app.

So if I went ahead with using phone gap, could I use the Google Maps Javascript API to build the navigation part of the app and then use PhoneGap to package it into an iOS/Android application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of cordova is that you always have good plugins which are relatively simple to install and use.One of the  plugins available for using google map in cordova apps is given below

```
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps
```

However you can also go ahead using the Google maps javascript API in cordova to build the navigation part of your application. I recently used this in my cordova app and it worked very well. I have used the features of Google maps like navigation, adding custom markers, place auto complete etc.

Comment: Any advice on pros/cons of using the plugin versus the Javascript API?

Comment: How about the API keys? how secure is the app in terms of making these keys publicly available? not sure though.